# How do I fill this form using mechanicalsoup or any other python library?

Tags: beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

```
  <div id='credentials' class='loggedout'>
      <input name='username' placeholder='Username' type='text'  id='username' size='30' maxlength='60'>
      <input name='password' placeholder='Password' type='password' id='password' size='30' autocomplete='off' maxlength='60' onfocus='if(this.value=="Password")this.value="";'>
  </div>
```

I have to fill `username` and `Password` in this snippet.
I use to use **mechanicalsoup** where this used to work:

browser.select_form(`CSS Selector`)
and then insert individual values as

> browser['username'] = umame
>
> browser['Password'] = pass

But there no form tag in this so I am not able do this.
Is there any way to achieve this.

Any help or advice is hearty appreciated!!
**Thanks**

Comment: Do you mean: it was working before with MechanicalSoup, but is no longer working? Indeed we made `select_form` more defensive, but perhaps we should revert this change if there's actual use-case where the defensive code is harmful.

Comment: `select_form` could work if there as  actual tag `form` that in the webpage. But in this case, there is none

Comment: Can you share the URL of the website you're trying to browse?